# Serializer and DateTime format - how to get only string with date

Tags: php, symfony

I writing a simple financial application. In this moment I working on API and created first method with GetAll() functionality that give me every record from table.
I've got 2 questions:

**Question number one:**

I using serializer from Serializer Component and got this view:

[my_api_response_view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWW77.png)

How to get string date format (for example - 2022-01-05) with serializer? I tried with DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY but it doesn't work.

**Question number two:**

Is there any instruction where to put Serializer encoders and normalizers and how to implement serializer object in controller? In documentation I can't see anything about where to put serializer components.

My Controller class with Serializer code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\InFlow;

use App\Entity\InFlow\InFlow;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;


class InFlowController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/in/flow', name: 'app_in_flow')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'Welcome to your new controller!',
            'path' => 'src/Controller/InFlowController.php',
        ]);
    }

    #[Route('/inflows', name: 'get_all_inflows')]
    public function getAll(EntityManagerInterface $em): JsonResponse {

        $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $inFlows = $em->getRepository(InFlow::class)->findAll();
        $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($inFlows, 'json', [DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'Y-m-d H:i:s']);
        return new JsonResponse(['Data'=>json_decode($jsonContent)], 200);
    }
}
```

My Entity Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\InFlow;

use App\Repository\InFlowRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: InFlowRepository::class)]
class InFlow
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $in_flow_name;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'float')]
    private $in_flow_value;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
    private $in_flow_date;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private $in_flow_comment;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getInFlowName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->in_flow_name;
    }

    public function setInFlowName(string $in_flow_name): self
    {
        $this->in_flow_name = $in_flow_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInFlowValue(): ?float
    {
        return $this->in_flow_value;
    }

    public function setInFlowValue(float $in_flow_value): self
    {
        $this->in_flow_value = $in_flow_value;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInFlowDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->in_flow_date;
    }

    public function setInFlowDate(\DateTimeInterface $in_flow_date): self
    {
        $this->in_flow_date = $in_flow_date;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getInFlowComment(): ?string
    {
        return $this->in_flow_comment;
    }

    public function setInFlowComment(?string $in_flow_comment): self
    {
        $this->in_flow_comment = $in_flow_comment;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: You should also include in your question, the relevant parts of the related entity if there is one. I'm just guessing from your output that you have the `'timestamp'` property stored as an `integer` and not an instance of `\DateTimeInterface` which I think will require you to use a custom normalizer.

Comment: @ArleighHix just edited my question with Entity Class.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `DateTimeNormalizer()` to your normalizer

```php
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;


    #[Route('/inflows', name: 'get_all_inflows')]
    public function getAll(EntityManagerInterface $em): JsonResponse {

        $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [
            new ObjectNormalizer()
            new DateTimeNormalizer([DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'Y-m-d h:m']), // date object return format
        ];
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $inFlows = $em->getRepository(InFlow::class)->findAll();
        $jsonContent = $serializer->normalize($inFlows, 'json', []);
        return new JsonResponse(['Data'=>json_decode($jsonContent)], 200);
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer but It doesn't work. I have still the same view.

Comment: @Sparrow3kk it work find for me, you should import `DateTimeNormalizer`  from `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer;`

Comment: yes, I have Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer; imported (you can see it on my controller code). Its weird. Anyway, thanks for answer, I will try to fix it.